# Using class object in different cpp file

Tags: c++, class

I was starting to learn to use class object in different .cpp file..

What I did:

1. Created a class of node in one file and saved it with node.h
2. Created another file with name node_pair.cpp and included node.h
3. Created a function named `pair()` and called it from `main()`

Now, I want to ask two things:

1. I am getting `error: reference to ‘pair’ is ambiguous`

Here is the code for node.h file

```
#include "iostream"
#include"stdlib"
using namespace std;

class node
{
    int data;
public:
    node *next;
    int insert(node*);
    node* create();
    int display(node *);
} *start = NULL, *front, *ptr, n;

int node::insert(node* np)
{
    if (start == NULL)
    {
        start = np;
        front = np;
    }
    else
    {
        front->next = np;
        front = np;
    }
    return 0;
}

node* node::create()
{
    node *np;
    np = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node)) ;
    cin >> np->data;
    np->next = NULL;
    return np;
}

int node::display(node* np)
{
    while (np != NULL)
    {
        cout << np->data;
        np = np->next;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main_node()
{
    int ch;
    cout << "enter the size of the link list:";
    cin >> ch;
    while (ch--)
    {   
        ptr = n.create();
        n.insert(ptr);
    }
    n.display(start);
    cout << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

and here is the code for node_pair.cpp

```
#include"iostream"
#include"node.h"
using namespace std;

node obj;

int pair()
{
    node* one, *two, *save;
    one = start;
    two = start->next;
    while (two != NULL)
    {
        save = two->next;
        two->next = one;
        one->next = save;
    } 
}

int main()
{
    main_node();
    pair();
    obj.display(start);
    return 0;
}
```

What should I do to resolve this error

And now the second problem

2. I want to keep `node* next` pointer to be private in node class but if I do so then I will not get access for it in `pair()` function.

Please answer, thanks in advance.

Comment: How is that valid C? Also, only one question per question. Next, what the ... does this have to do with node.js?

Comment: it's because you have `using namepsace std;` and [there is a std::pair](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair).  Your error is the textbook reason to **not** using namespace, you don't know everything in the `std` namespace and will likely get a collision eventually.

Comment: C++ does not have "class objects". A "class object" would be something like `String.class` in Java. In C++, classes are not objects.

Answer (score 2):

Some tips:

- Your function pair clashes with `std::pair`.
- Don't use `using namespace std;`. It's a bad practice and creates errors like this.
- Mixing node.js and C++ is an advanced topic. If you just begun to learn OOP, I recommend that you stick to pure C++.

Comment: Thank you for your use full suggestion... i will definitely keep this in mind

Answer (score 0):

You have a name collision with your `pair()` and `std::pair`.

Best practice is to avoid `using` the entire `namespace std` -- just use what you need. For example, if you only need `std::cin` you can use `using std::cin;` to add it to the global namespace but not `std::pair`. You can also replace all instances of `cin` with `std::cin` instead.

If you really want to use the entire `namespace std` you can also create your own `namespace` to put your code in -- in particular, you'd need to put your `pair()` in this new namespace. You do it like this:

```
namespace mynamespace {
  int pair() {
    // ...
  }

// ... other code in mynamespace
} // end mynamespace
```